# Arrange a Haft-Sin table

Tags: code-golf, string

It's [Nowruz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowruz) and you want to set up a [Haft-Sin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haft-sin) table by words. This means finding seven words that start with letter *s*.

## The Challenge

Write a program which its input is a list of words separated by space, and output at most first 7 words which starts by letter *s*. If the *s* is before letter *h* it doesn't count because it would not pronounce /s/.

#### Input

An arbitrary length string containing words separated by space.
Words must not contain anything other than letters (uppercase or lowercase) and numbers and `_`.

These inputs are valid:

```
hello Puzzle code_golf 12
Start say_hello separating_by_space_is_right
I am a valid word list
```

And these inputs are invalid:

```
code-golf, #invalid_word, separating_by_comma_is_wrong
I'm an invalid word list
```

#### Output

The first 7 words which starts by letter *S-s* and not followed by letter *H-h*, in every acceptable way (comma separated, space separated, new-line etc) and in any order.

- If two words are duplicate don't count them twice. Every single word
  is count once.
- If the input contains less that 7 word starting with *s* output nothing. Don't output the words.
- The output must contain the exact word which is in the input. So if the input contains `SuPER`, output should be `SuPER` and not `SUPER` or `super` or any other form of lower and upper case.
- Words pronunciation matter. The word `Speed` and `SPEED` both count the same. You may want to lowercase all the input and unique the words and then check for words.

#### test-cases

input:

```
speed speed new car book seven sad sum power fun super sister silver silly start
```

output:

```
speed seven sad sum super sister silver
```

input:

```
speed SpEEd new book seven sad sum power fun super sister silver silly start
```

output:

```
speed seven sad sum super sister silver
```

input:

```
sheep speed new car book seven sad sum power fun super sister silver silly start
```

output:

```
speed seven sad sum super sister silver
```

input:

```
first second third
```

output:

### Edited

This was my first question and I missed many special cases. I try to clarify them.

Comment: question: do the outputted words have to be in the same order as they appear in the input, or can they be in any order?

Comment: @des54321 I updated the question. The order does not matter.

Comment: Is it only lowercase `s` or must we handle uppercase `S` too? What about the `h`/`H`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan no, both are acceptable.

Comment: @JonathanAllan you were right, test case was incorrect. I update it.

Comment: What does "both are acceptable" mean?

Comment: @JonathanAllan **S** and **s** are acceptable. It is also for H and h.

Comment: I still don't know what that means. Some examples might help - must we output `Super` if its at the start? and should we exclude `sHould`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes. In fact lower and upper case doesn't matter. it important how to pronounce the word.

Comment: Does upper/lowercase matter for the "_If two words are duplicate don't count them twice. Every single word is count once._"? E.g. are `super`, `SUPER`, `sUpEr` three different words or three the same words?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen because they all have the same pronunciation they count ones. But for output, you can choose any of them you want.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi You may want to add a test case for that then, since almost all current answers fail. (E.g. `SPEED sPeEd shopper SPEED new car book seven sad sum power fun super sister silver silly start` → `SPEED seven sad sum super sister silver`)

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi (mine is one of the failing current answers) - please could you also clarify whether the output needs to be one of the upper/lowercase versions that are present in the input, or whether ```SUPER``` would be a valid output if the input contains ```SUPer``` and ```supER``` (since all are pronounced the same).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen The output must be the exact form of the input. If the input is the word `SUpEr` the output must show `SUpEr`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I updated the question. Thanks

Comment: @KevinCruijssen since all answers fail because I didn't have clarified well, should I change the rule in order to make current answers acceptable? I'm not familiar with rules in this site.

Comment: What is expected output for `see see see see see see see`? Should I output `see` as the input contains at least 7 `s` started words? Suggest add a test case `see seE sEe sEE See SeE SEe SEE`.

Comment: Please, run your future questions through [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active).

Comment: Must the casing in the ouput match the casing in the input? e.g., if the input is all uppercase, could the output be all lowercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>Assuming that we must handle uppercase `S` and `H` too and that we must/may return the leftmost distinct "s-words"</sup>

```
ḣ2ŒliⱮ⁼Ø.
ḲQçƇ⁾hsḣJf7ḢƊ$
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of characters and yields a list of the words.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUw9CsIwFN49xRucHVy8g07SE0R95UVjE/Kalo6dCo5Ozjq4CTp1EJdi79FeJKZY@H754NujUoX3XX2bf89K9s9HX76by2zS1a91c2@rvvwQh3kZL7r62p6mvqlW3rNB3MGoQEAMIoCAhSFpEZi0U2EjYYYiAoF57AnmsBUWNlofIMIME2B3BKNztBC7BCJnQmIRDiSnQ5Qq@5sqgFNh0x8)**

#### How?

```
ḣ2ŒliⱮ⁼Ø. - Helper Link, valid word?: list of characters, Word; identifiers ("hs")
ḣ2        - head Word to index two   - e.g. "Child" -> "Ch"
  Œl      - lower-case -> X                     -> X = "ch"
     Ɱ    - map across C in identifiers with:
    i     -   first (1-indexed) index of C in X     -> [2,0]
                                                    ('h' at index 2, no 's' exists)
       Ø. - [0,1]
      ⁼   - equal?

ḲQçƇ⁾hsḣJf7ḢƊ$ - Link get s-words: list of characters, T
Ḳ              - split T at space characters -> Words
 Q             - deduplicate
    ⁾hs        - set the right argument to "hs"
   Ƈ           - filter keep those Words for which:
  ç            -   call the helper Link as a dyad - f(Word, "hs")
             $ - last two links as a monad - f(ValidWords):
            Ɗ  -   last three links as a monad - g(ValidWords):
        J      -     range of length -> [1,2,...,number of valid words]
          7    -     seven
         f     -     filter-keep -> [7] or [] if less than seven valid words
           Ḣ   -     head        -> 7   or 0
       ḣ       -   head of ValidWords to that index
```

Comment: `SPEED sPeEd shopper SPEED new car book seven sad sum power fun super sister silver silly start` should result in `SPEED seven sad sum super sister silver`, so a simply deduplicate won't suffice in this case.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 28 bytes

```
⌈'⇩ḣh\h≠$h\s=∧;:ɽ:vḟUİ₅6>7*Ẏ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLijIgn4oep4bijaFxcaOKJoCRoXFxzPeKIpzs6yb06duG4n1XEsOKChTY+Nyrhuo4iLCIiLCJTUEVFRCBzUGVFZCBzaG9wcGVyIFNQRUVEIG5ldyBjYXIgYm9vayBzZXZlbiBzYWQgc3VtIHBvd2VyIGZ1biBzdXBlciBzaXN0ZXIgc2lsdmVyIHNpbGx5IHN0YXJ0Il0=) or [Try some testcases!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#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) Mis-deduplication should be fixed now.

```
⌈'⇩ḣh\h≠$h\s=∧;:ɽ:vḟUİ₅6>7*Ẏ
⌈'             ;                 Filter input, split on spaces, by:
  ⇩ḣ                                 Push (input lowercased)([0], [1:])
    h\h≠                             Second character (input[1:][0]) isn't `h`
        $h\s=∧                       and first character isn `s`

                :ɽ               Duplicate, lowercase each
                  :vḟ            Find first occurrences of each of ^ in ^
                     U           Uniquify ^
                      İ          Index ^ into filtered list, resulting
                                 in the properly deduplicated list

                       ₅6>       1 if len(^) is 7 or more, otherwise 0
                          7*Ẏ    Multiply by 7 and slice [0:that]
```

Comment: `SPEED sPeEd shopper SPEED new car book seven sad sum power fun super sister silver silly start` should result in `SPEED seven sad sum super sister silver`, so a simply uniquify won't suffice in this case.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen that should be fixed now

Comment: Great, +1 from me. :)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>57</s> <s>61</s> <s>58</s> 79 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to "regex stealing" by pajonk*

*Edit2: +21 bytes to remove case-sensitive duplicates, while returning the originally cased input*

```r
q=(o=grep("^s(?!h)",scan(,""),T,T,T))[!duplicated(tolower(o))];if(q[7]>F)q[1:7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBDoIwEER/Zempm3DxRKJBL@KZRG8EkwqLECst3Rbi11fQzOElLzPjYpxyafKnIyvFneUp6VGk3KhRpkJgetuCWCVtsHpolKdWeqPNQk4axPowdHKqsvp4wana7bM6XsuiOAOXVLTAwL2xlhz87UgLNMrBw5gXMM00Aqu1Ft5gt0vowmrCNuCB/Q96/kN/gL1yPn4B)

Outputs the first 7 unique words starting with 's' or 'S' but not 'sh' or 'Sh', if there are at least 7.
Otherwise errors without outputting anything.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>59</s> <s>63</s> <s>61</s> 82 bytes

```r
(q=(o=grep("^s(?!h)",scan(,""),T,T,T))[!duplicated(tolower(o))])[1:7][length(q)>6]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBCsIwEER/ZZvTBnrxoiBUL/Ze0FupENu1FWOSZpMWvz62ljk8eMyMTwnHAm3Re3Io7oznbJAi51YZzIWQ@W2NlHXWRadfrQrUYbDazuTRStnIenc8NLUm04cBR3naN@laleUFuKKyAwYerHPkYbOGZmiVh4e1b2CayACrpRY/4NZTeMbFxHXALw5/6GmD/gIH5UP6AQ)

As above, but exits quietly without erroring if there are less than 7 valid words.

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYpBDsIgEEWvMrKChI2rJjXqJdw1NcE6tcTKUAZKenpEm794Ly8/lELn5OySUL4CeinuLK@HSQnNg3FSC6H07TelTnaU1DX9pTbqjm3TF/aIT@CJMuzqMMNgAjyI3sC4ogM29ZE@4CljgDHVknw1thz/mNcd8wYcTYjlCw "R – Try It Online") by stealing regex from other answers.

Comment: @pajonk - Thanks!  I even think I saw it, but didn't understand it, and didn't try it out...  Now I need to figure-out how it works...

Comment: "Negative lookahead" is the search term to look for. [Example link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#:~:text=Positive%20and-,Negative%20Lookahead,-Negative%20lookahead%20is)

Comment: `SPEED sPeEd shopper SPEED new car book seven sad sum power fun super sister silver silly start` should result in `SPEED seven sad sum super sister silver`, so a simply uniquify won't suffice in this case.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - Thanks for spotting.  I've now read all the (still partial) rule clarifications in the comments, but it now isn't clear to me whether ```speed``` would be a valid output for your example: will fix once this is specified...

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - Fixed now, but it cost a lot...

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>62</s>  61 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @l4m2*

```javascript
s=>(a=[...new Set(s.match(/\bs(?!h)\w*/g))]).slice(a[6]||7,7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU2xEoIwFNv9iidT62nZZEI/whEYSnlAtVCur8B5x7/XKptLkktyyVMukpTTk7@MtsHQ5oHyG5N5IYQYcYUHekZikF71LC1rYvdjz8v1lHacV1yQ0QqZLK7VtmXnjAdlR7IGhbEda1lCE2IDO37nlHRQW/sCwgVHIBnDeYDJruignaMzT1GRJv8js@xk3kBeOp9wfvi7aLUjH/ei3YDvtWtiKXwA)

Comment: `s` does not appear to register as a valid word.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Well, I guess `s` should be matched indeed. Now fixed.

Comment: [61](https://tio.run/##XU2xEoIwFNv9iidT62nZZEI/whEYSnlAtVCur8B5x7/XKptLkktyyVMukpTTk7@MtsHQ5oHyG5N5IYQYcYUHekZikF71LC1rYvdjz8v1lHacV1yQ0QqZLK7VtmXnjAdlR7IGhbEda1lCE2IDO37nlHRQW/sCwgVHIBnDeYDJruignaMzT1GRJv8js@xk3kBeOp9wfvi7aLUjH/ei3YDvtWtiKXwA)

Comment: @l4m2 I think `a[6]` may be a number.

Comment: @Arnauld How can a number start with `s`?

Comment: @l4m2 Good point. :-p

Comment: This doesn't seem to be case-insensitive (see second test case).

Comment: @Shaggy Hmm. It looks like the challenge spec has been heavily modified since I answered it. :-/

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 47 bytes

```
+msi`(^(.+)$.+)^\2$
$1
Gi`^s(?!h)
1!`.+(¶.+){6}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fO7c4M0EjTkNPW1MFiONijFS4VAy53DMT4oo17BUzNLkMFRP0tDUObQPKVpvV/v9fXJCamsIFIfNSy7mSE4u4kvLzs7mKU8tS87iKE4GSpblcBfnlqUVcaaVAkdICIKs4s7gETOWUQaicSq7iksSiEgA) Explanation:

```
+msi`(^(.+)$.+)^\2$
$1
```

Delete case-insensitive duplicates.

```
Gi`^s(?!h)
```

Keep only words beginning with `s` but not `sh`.

```
1!`.+(¶.+){6}
```

Select the first seven words.

Comment: What about the lone word, `s`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I should have guessed...

Comment: `SPEED sPeEd shopper SPEED new car book seven sad sum power fun super sister silver silly start` should result in `SPEED seven sad sum super sister silver`, so a simply uniquify won't suffice in this case.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Better now?

Comment: @Neil Yep, +1 from me. :)

Comment: 34 bytes in Retina 1: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/30UlgUvFR0WNyz0zNyGuWMNeMUOTyychTk9b49A2PW3NarPa//@LC1JTU7ggZF5qOVdyYhFXUn5@NldxallqHldxIlCyNJerIL88tYgrrRQoUloAZBVnFpeAqZwyCJVTyVVcklhUAgA "Retina – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 27 (or 22?) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
#ʒlć'sQsн'hÊ*}DlDÙkèDg7@7*£
```

Assumes differently cased words (e.g. `speed`/`SPEED`/`sPeEd`) are all the same for the uniquify. Otherwise this could have been 22 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) by replacing the `DlDÙkè` with `Ù`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f@dSknCPt6sWBxRf2qmcc7tKqVXDJcTk8M/vwCpd0cwdzrUOL//8PDnB1dVEoDkh1TVEILnBNBbILUlNTFPJSyxWSE4sUkvLzsxWKU8tS8xSKE1MUiktzFQryy1OLFNJKgSKlBUBWcWZxCZjKKYNQOZUKxSWJRSUA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##rYwxDoJAEEV7T/GjBYmxt9QCeownWNhRNiBLdhYMibaaWNJZ23gJG7Gy8gxeBDdS25lM/v@ZP/M0i0hRt6vq2RDvQ4PhrO5GzyZ7HD1e8OvmJe1pvPczvz2n7dVfT@fT8f3STbplGAQ@OKRAYlkE5HJBJJHTFrEwiLROwVRRDhYSXG5Q6C0ZrEq3KQuXWLH9Wlb1ltVgK4wd9Kg/AlfKsHXfsc4lbKKMHDDYTdIfOIByIsDRzwIcfwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
#          # Split the (implicit) input-string by spaces
 ʒ         # Filter this list of words by:
  l        #  Convert it to lowercase
   ć       #  Extract head; pop remainder-string and first char separated
    'sQ   '#  Check if this head is an "s"
   s       #  Swap so the remainder-string is at the top
    н      #  Pop and push its first character
     'hÊ  '#  Check that it's NOT equal to a "h"
   *       #  Check that both were truthy
 }D        # After the filter: duplicate the resulting list of words
   l       # Convert each to lowercase
    D      # Duplicate it again
     Ù     # Uniquify the top copy
      k    # Get all its indices in the lowercase list
       è   # Use it to index in the regular case-insensitive list
   D       # Duplicate the list
    g      # Pop and push its length
     7@    # Check if it's >=7
       7*  # Multiply that 0/1 by 7 (either 0 or 7)
         £ # Leave that many leading words from the list
           # (after which the resulting list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 60 bytes

```perl
my%s;$_=(@r=grep!$s{lc$_}++,/\bs(?!h)\w*/gi)<7?"":"@r[0..6]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY7LCsJADEX3fkUsFdT62qigFt30C1xakT6iHRw7IZlaRPx1x2I/QTf3hIQcLiHruXO3R0/W/ins7zi8MFLXl6fO/NMrCEbTOJX@tlsM4no4vajBZrn1vJW348NsMlkcPeeEEHNos8QasoQhNeYKgncsQZLmWN2ATI0M56rZVNRMosR@oe8t9APEJmw7rWpPUdQKf5MViPTPdmfFYpvvzJQ52EJx/jZklSnFjRPSHw)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>111</s> <s>102</s> 103 bytes

I am pretty sure this isn't a perfect solution, as my regex skills are far from perfect and this seems an unnecessarily long way to check for "any word character that is not h or H", but it works. Takes a list of the words, and returns a set of the seven words, or nothing if it cannot find seven words.

```python
import re
def f(x):
 r=set()
 for i in x:
  if re.match("[Ss](?![Hh])",i):r|={i}
  if len(r)>6:return r
```

Edit -9 bytes: realized that it didn't have to check if the words only contained alphanumerics

Edit +1 bytes: @a stone arachnid pointed out my regex failed for input of `s`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1RS8NAEITf8yuWe7oTU4SCaKD1h9giZ7JnliZ3x@6mabX@9ngYEHyZGWY/dvJV@xS3T5mXhcacWIGx6jBAsBfXVMA7QbWugpAYCCjCpbRAoXCb0WvbW2NfyMmrrz@o/nyon9@Oh/nO3JNr@Lb7ou8VHzBadvvHhlEnjsBLZopqgzWSETtYNeIMrWd4T@kEgmeMIL4cpxFympEhTKWZcklCor82nFcbriDqWc1G8kBqDRjnXPW3E4hFy9M2xQ60J@7@k8sP)

Comment: unfortunately @astonearachnid, that does not fully (to my understanding, at least) match the challenge spec, as that will match non-word characters as well, and the challenge was not specific (to my reading) on whether the input will contain invalid words or if it will only be valid words

Comment: actually @astonearachnid youre right, I skipped over a bit of the input specification when I was reading it

Comment: @des54321 The thing we actually want to use here is a negative lookahead, so `s(?!h)`.

Comment: @Lazy that only works if we dont need to handle uppercase, which I think we do, and thus we'd need `[sS](?![hH])`, 1 byte longer than what I have

Comment: @des54321 my mistake, using `[^hH]` fails for input of `s` while `[sS](?![hH])` does not.

Comment: oh true point @astonearachnid, I absolutely missed that

Comment: `SPEED sPeEd shopper SPEED new car book seven sad sum power fun super sister silver silly start` should result in `SPEED seven sad sum super sister silver` (single case-insensitive 'speed'), so a simply uniquify won't suffice in this case.

Comment: scratch the regex for [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##VY5PS8RADMXv/RSPXjpzEUUQKeyevXuUPdRthgZrZkjS/YP62etoQfCSl7z3I0m5@pTl/rHouo6UkMIl9g10Z@QhNkhZwWDBpbrgBH65PbB09twNMtZpJgkc93cHyV65bnrqev3cffDXxv/kGvcPvZIvKtC1KIuHFForRCO2KnTGcVC85vwGoxMJbKjh8o6Sz6RIS3WWUjtj81@ZT5vMV5gP6u2NlZk9tGhjjM3fncRqXpcec/3YJ9bxP7l@Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>78</s> 75 bytes

```powershell
($r=-split$args-match'^s[^h]*$'|?{!($_-in$u);$u+=,$_})[0..6]*($r.count-ge7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZBBT8JAEIXP7a8Ym4202BJPeiCNJASvGjkSIMsypdXSXXd2QYP97XWxQjAx8aRednbnzfvmZZXcoqYcyzIRUmPDsnTXhEynCamyMIzrFSVrbkTemdFklk@7rPN2szsL2TwpKmajPrMXaczmdTS57PWupl1n7glpK5Os8Dpqat8fhL4XD8KAFOIS2rPCLQiuYSHlExBusALiTrRrUPtIkFnXscrdqCDzUcpNW8pXIMO1CWI4ML8AvrEF0WmEsRqN2gh/vT5HVP/8A/ArIeCnGIf9WaHJuDkhqyWYvNDLvd@pEbzBrdQjLvLkbvGIwsDO95hBMkNOGAPDF@W6bksKbN53mkaypXHPc5bBcdIpk/vx0JKR6xY0hYFDeWMrBBLt7UdUgs8QfIIC5/QeDszTbu3XzTs)

-3 bytes thanks to *mazzy*!

Comment: nice. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZBBT8JAEIXP7a8Ym4202BJPeiCNJASvGjkSIMsypdXSXXd2QYP97XWxQjAx8aRednbnzfvmZZXcoqYcyzIRUmPDsnTXhEynCamyMIzrFSVrbkTemdFklk@7rPN2szsL2TwpKmajPrMXaczmdTS57PWupl1n7glpK5Os8Dpqat8fhL4XD8KAFOIS2rPCLQiuYSHlExBusALiTrRrUPtIkFnXscrdqCDzUcpNW8pXIMO1CWI4ML8AvrEF0WmEsRqN2gh/vT5HVP/8A/ArIeCnGIf9WaHJuDkhqyWYvNDLvd@pEbzBrdQjLvLkbvGIwsDO95hBMkNOGAPDF@W6bksKbN53mkaypXHPc5bBcdIpk/vx0JKR6xY0hYFDeWMrBBLt7UdUgs8QfIIC5/QeDszTbu3XzTs "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) for Windows, 68 bytes

*Thanks @[Julian](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/245651/80745) for the inspiration*

```powershell
($r=$args|sls '\bs(?!h)\S*'-a|% m*|% v*e|sort -u -t 7)*!($r.count-7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1ZNNT8MwDIbPza8wpUA7LVx3QBNI07gysQMHQCjrPFromhInG9O63z68ZHzdQYJL/MZ2Hr@t5EYv0VCBVSVzbXBLaKWqSkVA2lh/SD15wtzCIXD2pqynekkw@ngnRDLrr7dpYvqJMo/UUkVwcjeh9PygyO7GnROp2iOYd/hYdLD1XOlAWuhlnQN@d5prV1vZy7YbIS5SEXXTmBrEKYSzxiXkysBE62cgXGANpLjo5tDsbMDMccY1rKgk60O1CKFaAVllbNwVURSocRdiT/FChbubh8AQLzwnqB1qr6qVFx6YiS9Gx81wGIz@TZMFYvMv/ib8klU/6ef9zkpDvCWY63oKtijNlCsZtHCpzVDlhbwKu7MWUWKR7EARdiHB14az/IV9SB7OuGaQXGX5epzM4KOTK7ej8cCR1fMAuocLRkVjl@dIxP1xkn7S2m/7Kq1ueMVikPji@/ZDQlcWMz26fp8b76u77EZstm8)

The alias `sort` is not defined for Linux PowerShell and TIO. Linux requires `sort-object`.

Less golfed:

```powershell
$result = $args|select-string '\bs(?!h)\S*' -allMatches|% matches|% value|sort -unique -top 7
$result*($result.count-eq7)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υι≔Φυ∧›⁼↧§ι⁰s⁼↧§ι¹h⁼κ⌕↧υ↧ιυ…υ∧‹⁶Ｌυ⁷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/NbsMgDMfvfgqUE0hMWi/doaeoSqdKPVTqE7DgJagMGIZkfXoGm6bc5oM/f5b/HmcVR69sKetsLDJ@diGnW4rGTVwIds008yyZEQfoiczk@MnYhLE1e6f5a0TVyuEzK0v84leMoyLkfTo7jV/cSPYsJOuoq/4/ateouRMbdpfsZOqNDc91uFVGNJMsV3HXqjjx42O0eJx9@JN3QSK@r0voplQ/afhLXTqUQgFRwy0MgwaHK7x5fwfCBR2Q0kD5A0I7Be@5dnKoGRlKP8Euv8E@gJKKCcrTYr8B) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated strings. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Input the list of words.

```
≔Φυ∧›⁼↧§ι⁰s⁼↧§ι¹h⁼κ⌕↧υ↧ιυ
```

Case-insensitively filter out all words that don't start with an `s` or start with `sh` or are duplicate.

```
…υ∧‹⁶Ｌυ⁷
```

Output the first seven remaining words if there are more than six of them.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 21 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I think this is right; it's been a *long* day so I'm not at all sure!

```
¸fÈÎos «XÅÎohÃòk mÎ¯7
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=uGbIzm9zIKtYxc5vaMPyayBtzq83&input=IlNIZWVwIGZpcnN0IHNwZWVkIFNwRUVkIG5ldyBib29rIHNldmVuIHNhZCBzdW0gcG93ZXIgZnVuIHN1cGVyIHNpc3RlciBzaWx2ZXIgc2lsbHkgc3RhcnQiCi1R)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 64 bytes

```javascript
s=>(a=s.match(/(\bs(?!h)\w*\b)(?<!\b\1 .*)/gi)).slice(a[6]||7,7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYyxDoIwFEV3v@LJ1BKFuOgiMvEFjtah0AdUC236CsTEf8dGN6dzc3JzHnKW1Hjtwn60Cte2WKm4MFlQNsjQ9CxnoiZWbnsullTUnJXnrajFAbKU553mPCOjG2Tydry/36fdia@NHckazIztWMsScogKrq6qFIy4QG3tEwhnHIGkApoGcHZBD@0UzeTiIk3hCzP/YF5AQfqQcL75y7faU4i9qBWEXnsVT@sH)

Fixed Arnauld's uppercase problem with 3 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://www.php.net/), <del>134</del> 131 bytes

```
$a=explode(" ",$argn);foreach($a as$v){$l=strtolower($v);if($l[0]=="s"&&$l[1]<>"h"){$b[$l]="$v ";if(count($b)==7){echo join($b);}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7BTsMwEER/ZWWtKkcCCU4cUsOF9ozEscrBSTY4xfVaXicFVfl1ggOXeaOnOUx0cd2/xJJoDX1Fzz1pBeoObfoIVT1wIts5jRas4Fzd0BvJKbPnKyVdTD0OGv3poTFGidrtSn9s9s/KqTJuT@gbo3AGte06nkLW2FbGPFU36hzDmcewmXpZlnUVRxRBIlEP72@HwysEukJnE7TMnyA0UwCxPch0gbhdgGEqZoqlySj5D37@h/8GyTblH4555CDr/fEX)

Explanation: Used associative array key to prevent dups instead of in_array function.

----- Previous answer -----

```
$a=explode(" ",$argn);foreach($a as$v){if($v[0]=="s"&&$v[1]<>"h"&&!in_array($v,$b)&&$i<7){$b[]=$v;$i++;}}if($i==7){echo join($b," ");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BS8QwEIX/yhiGpWUr6MlDG724ngWPS5FpOzXRmoRMm3VZ@tetUS/zPt57zAsmbM1DyBdJ81eY/MCFAlUhxTdX1qOPTL0pkIAEU3mxY4HpeNNqrUTtdplv2@ZemcxX1r1SjHTOjQq7Mqe2uSsv2B1bjalGu9/X6/r7wWqdA@6Nh3dvXYFdlUfLet02McwBJDAP8PJ8ODyC4xP0FKHz/gOEEzsQGkCWTwj@xBHGJTtLyCRW5j@Z0r9MZ5CZ4vztw2y9k@366Qc)

Explanation: Straightforward conversion of input to array, step through array testing each word against the rules, if a word passes the test add it to second array, and only print second array if 7 words pass the test.